# Question about a proof regarding cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We proved this lemma in my class

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $H\leq G$. Then
>   \begin{equation}
> \phi:(G/{\sim})=G/H \to H\backslash G =(G/{\approx}),
> \end{equation}
>   with $\phi(Hg)=g^{-1}H$, is bijective.

The relation $\sim$ and $\approx$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
g_1 \sim g_2 \iff g_1g_2^{-1} \in H \\
g_1 \approx g_2 \iff g_2^{-1}g_1 \in H.
\end{equation}

The proof given to us is this:

> **Proof:**
>   First, we're going to see that $\phi$ is well defined.
>   \begin{equation}
> g_1 \sim g_2 \iff g_1g_2^{-1} \in H \iff \exists\ h\in H\ \text{such that}\ g_1g_2^{-1}=h \iff\\ \iff \exists\ h\in H\ \text{such that}\ g_1=hg_2 \iff g_1^{-1}=g_2^{-1}h^{-1}, \text{for}\ h^{-1} \in H \iff \\ \iff g_{2}g_1^{-1}\in H \iff g_1^{-1} \approx g_2^{-1}.
> \end{equation}
>   Then we see that $Hg_1=Hg_2 \iff g_1^{-1}H=g_2^{-1}H$, and it means that $\phi$ is well defined and injective.

Then he sees that $\phi$ is exhaustive too, but the part that I don't understand of the proof is the one above. I don't understand why he says that $Hg_1=Hg_2 \iff g_1^{-1}H=g_2^{-1}H$. How he concludes that from $g_1\sim g_2 \iff g_1^{-1} \approx g_2^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $Hg_1 = Hg_2$. Since $g_1 \in Hg_1$, so does $g_1 \in Hg_2$. Thus $g_1 = hg_2$ for some $h\in H$. Taking inverses, $g_1^{-1} = (hg_2)^{-1}$. Since $(hg_2)^{-1} = g_2^{-1}h^{-1}$, we have $g_1^{-1} = g_2^{-1}h^{-1}$. Pre-multiplying by $g_2$ yields $g_2g_1^{-1} = h^{-1}$. As $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $h \in H$, so is $h^{-1}\in H$. Therefore, $g_2g_1^{-1} \in H$. That is, $(g_2^{-1})^{-1}g_1^{-1}\in H$. Thus, $g_1^{-1} \approx g_2^{-1}$. To prove the converse, retrace these steps backwards.

Comment: Hi kobe. Why $g_1 \in Hg_1$?

Comment: It's because $g_1 = eg_1$ and $e\in H$ (as $H$ is a subgroup of $G$).

Comment: Right! Thank you very much.